# You have money for $6$ pieces of candy. There are three flavors, $A,B,C$ to choose from. How many different selections can you make?

Tags: combinatorics

> You have money for $6$ pieces of candy. There are three flavors, $A,B,C$ to choose from. How many different selections can you make?

Use the formula $^{n+r-1}C_r$, where $r=6$  and $n=3$ and get $28$ selections.

My question is how is this formula derived? Because I don't understand where $n+r-1$ comes from. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the question is quite good but it's very easy to think. Think this way, we have an equation $x+ y+ z=6$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the respective numbers of candies bought in respective flavors $A$, $B$ and $C.$

Now think it this way, take a sequence of characters containing 6 candies(represented by '$.$') and the flavors as containers, separated by walls(represented by '|'). The string turns out out to be arbitrarily ('$..|...|.$').

some ways are as follows

$$...|..|.$$$$....|.|.$$$$.....|.|$$$$.|....|.$$ and so on.

Note that I have taken arbitrary no. of candies for each flavor so the '$|$'s (walls) would have arbitrary positions throughout the string. Now just calculate the no. of ways we can arrange the **walls** as well as **"dots"** and you will understand the rest.

Comment: @ronald , was I able to answer your question?

Comment: This is unexpected. I guess I'm terrible at math. Is (1) ||...... and (2) ......|| considered the same case? Also how does this relate to $n+r-1$? Thanks.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson, No they are not considered the same, Because the first represents there are 6 candies of Flavor $C$ and the second represent there are 6 candies of flavor $A$

Comment: Thank you for that answer. So I put seven sweets in a row. I pick two numbers I, j and put borders before sweet I and j, i and j may be the same. So the answer equals the number of ways to pick two possibly equal sweets out of 7. Or two different sweets out of eight. And that can be done similar with more types of sweets. Never thought of this.

Comment: @gnasher729,can you please Elaborate what you mean to say, Are you referring to this question?